# Incrementing counter for each item in a newsfeed

Tags: reactjs

I have prepared a view that cycles through an array of objects with properties for different feed items, rendering a Facebook-like feed. In each item, there is a "like" button with a count.

I'd like to be able to increment the count for that item's like count. The problem is that I don't seem to be able to know how to access an individual item (in the array)'s state and have the `incrementLikes` method increment just that item's like count (just on the client side view now; server side integration will happen later).

Code:

```
  var ItemList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var itemNodes = this.props.data.reverse().map(function(item) {
        return (
          <div key={item.uuid} className="feedItem">
            <a href={item.clickUrl}><img src={item.thumbnail} className="thumbnail" /></a>
            <div className="title">
              <a href={item.clickUrl}><h2>{item.title}</h2></a>
            </div>
            <div className="subtitle">
              <a href={item.clickUrl}><h3>{item.subtitle}</h3></a>
            </div>
            <div className="meta">
              <div className="likes">
                Likes: <span onClick={this.props.onClickEvent}>{item.likeCount}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          );
      });
      return (
        <div className="itemList">
          {itemNodes}
        </div>
        );
    }
  });
  var Feed = React.createClass({
    loadItemsFromServer: function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({data: data.contentFeed.items});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
      });
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
      this.loadItemsFromServer();
      setInterval(this.loadItemsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
    },
    incrementLikes: function(event) {
      var tempState = {};
      tempState.data.likeCount = this.state.data.likeCount + 1;
      this.setState({data: tempState});
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div className="feed">
          <ItemList data={this.state.data} onClickEvent={this.incrementLikes} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  });
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Feed url="content.json" pollInterval={5000} />,
    document.getElementById('react-content')
    );
```

In `ItemList` I'm currently returning HTML instead of another Component. I sense that this is the source of the problem but am at a bit of a loss at how to replace the `.map()` invocation that generates the `ItemNodes` with Componentry that can share data across its ancestors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have some kind of identifier for `item`, like `item.id`, you can achieve this through passing the `item.id` when the click occurs on the likes:

```
<div className="likes">
    Likes: <span onClick={function() { this.props.onClickEvent(item.id)}.bind(this)}>{item.likeCount}</span>
</div>
```

Or if you have arrow functions:

```
<div className="likes">
    Likes: <span onClick={() => this.props.onClickEvent(item.id)}>{item.likeCount}</span>
</div>
```

You could then slightly change your state representation (from an array to an object:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {likes: {}};
},
```

And then store likes in state against the `item.id`:

```
incrementLikes: function(itemId) {
  this.state.likes[itemId] = this.state.likes[itemId] ? this.state.likes[itemId] + 1 : 1;
  this.setState({likes:this.state.likes});
},
```